# Exporting JavaFX project with ant

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, javafx

I'm having a few issues exporting my JavaFX project as an executable jar file, I'm using the following ant script:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project name="A2-Computing-Coursework" default="do-deploy" basedir="."  xmlns:fx="javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant">
    <target name="init-fx-tasks">
        <path id="fxant">
            <filelist>
                <file name="${java.home}\..\lib\ant-javafx.jar"/>
                <file name="${java.home}\lib\jfxrt.jar"/>
            </filelist>
        </path>

        <taskdef resource="com/sun/javafx/tools/ant/antlib.xml"
            uri="javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant"
            classpathref="fxant"/>
    </target>
    <target name="setup-staging-area">
        <delete dir="externalLibs" />
        <delete dir="project" />
        <delete dir="projectRefs" />

        <mkdir dir="externalLibs" />

        <copy todir="externalLibs">
            <fileset dir="C:\Users\alexb\Documents\GitHub\A2-Computing-Coursework\resources">
                <filename name="sqlite-jdbc-3.8.10.1.jar"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>

        <mkdir dir="project" />
        <copy todir="project">
            <fileset dir="C:\Users\alexb\Documents\GitHub\A2-Computing-Coursework">
                <include name="src/**" />
            </fileset>
        </copy>

        <mkdir dir="projectRefs" />
    </target>
    <target name='do-compile'>
        <delete dir="build" />
        <mkdir dir="build/src" />
        <mkdir dir="build/libs" />
        <mkdir dir="build/classes" />

        <!-- Copy project-libs references -->
        <copy todir="build/libs">
            <fileset dir="externalLibs">
                <include name="sqlite-jdbc-3.8.10.1.jar"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>

        <!-- Copy project references -->

        <!-- Copy project sources itself -->
        <copy todir="build/src">
            <fileset dir="project/src">
                <include name="**/*"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>

        <javac includeantruntime="false" source="1.8" target="1.8" srcdir="build/src" destdir="build/classes" encoding="Cp1252">
            <classpath>
                <fileset dir="build/libs">
                    <include name="*"/>
                </fileset>
            </classpath>
        </javac>

        <!-- Copy over none Java-Files -->
        <copy todir="build/classes">
        <fileset dir="project/src">
            <exclude name="**/*.java"/>
        </fileset>
        </copy>


    </target>
    <target name="do-deploy" depends="setup-staging-area, do-compile, init-fx-tasks">
        <delete file="dist"/>
        <delete file="deploy" />

        <mkdir dir="dist" />
        <mkdir dir="dist/libs" />

        <copy todir="dist/libs">
            <fileset dir="externalLibs">
                <include name="*" />
            </fileset>
        </copy>


        <fx:resources id="appRes">
            <fx:fileset dir="dist" includes="A2-Computing-Coursework.jar"/>
            <fx:fileset dir="dist" includes="libs/*"/>
        </fx:resources>

        <fx:application id="fxApplication"
            name="A2-Computing-Coursework"
            mainClass="net.Bancey.A2COMP2CW.GUI"
        />

        <mkdir dir="build/classes/META-INF" />



        <fx:jar destfile="dist/A2-Computing-Coursework.jar">
            <fx:application refid="fxApplication"/>
            <fileset dir="build/classes">
            </fileset>
            <fx:resources refid="appRes"/>

            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Implementation-Vendor" value="Bancey"/>
                <attribute name="Implementation-Title" value="A2-Computing-Coursework"/>
                <attribute name="Implementation-Version" value="1.0.1"/>
                <attribute name="JavaFX-Feature-Proxy" value="None"/>
            </manifest>
        </fx:jar>




    </target>
</project>
```

It builds and exports successfully but when I try to run the jar file a windows pops up on the screen, it generates my database file but then it closes, I have no problem running my project in eclipse this leads me to believe that I'm missing referenced libraries in my jar. Does anyone know if this would cause this issue, and how I would ammend my ANT script?

Kind Regards,
Alex

Comment: Do you see any exceptions in the console?

Comment: @ItachiUchiha I have not errors in the console no

Comment: Do you run it using `java -jar A2-Computing-Coursework.jar` via the console?